# scaling ec2 on demand , lambda style

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I am new to AWS and I am completely lost. I am losing hope.

What I want to do seems quite easy, but I cannot find any clear streamlined documentation.
I would like to have my current web server call some API with an http request, and  get some value returned from the API. The values to return are computed by some Python script.
Now lambda would do the job, but I need to run it on an EC2 because of computational demand (16 cores needed).
On top of that, this would need to scale: process each api request on a different machine with its own 16 cores. If I have 100 calls, I should get 100 EC2 running in parallel.
When there is no API call, I should have 0 EC2 running and $0.00 charged.

Normally, for a given session, several calls will come in a period of about 10 mins, and these calls should be answered quickly. What I am thinking is maybe having a special first call that starts an EC2 for 20 mins. So that first call can take 20 seconds, but the subsequent ones should be very quickly answered.

```
Summary of what I need AWS to do:
 - Receive "start" API Call (Amazon API Gateway ?)
 - Start an EC2 specifically for that session for 20 mins
 - Return EC2 address (?)
 - Call script on EC2 through http requests
 - Stop EC2 after 20 mins or after the last call
```

What would be the services to set up and configure for that ?

I can create a docker image with the script if needed. (is there actually another way ?)

Is it possible ? How ?

Thanks a lot

Edit: modified a bit the question to reflect time constraints.

Comment: Where is your API hosted?

Comment: How long does an API take to process (eg 5 seconds or 5 minutes)? How quickly does the API need to process the request (eg can it wait 20 seconds, or 2 minutes, or 20 minutes)? Would you consider sending the requests to a queue and available machines process the messages when capacity is available, rather than having a "wait for a response" API? Can each machine only process one request (using all 16 cores), or can a machine process multiple simultaneously? Feel free to edit your question with such details.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to reflect time constraints.
At the beginning of a session, I can wait some time to start an EC2 for 20 min. But the subsequent calls should be answered almost immediately.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I am the founder of this
https://hakuna.cloud starts and stops  EC2 instances accordingly to real-time incoming requests, exactly how you described the workflow. It will start your instance on the first incoming request, and then stop it if no new requests are received within a given timeframe.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should look into AWS batch. This allows you to run a batch of jobs and you can use machines with more vCPUs and benefit from per second billing.

https://aws.amazon.com/batch/